# cx_Freeze : DLL load error with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze, setup.py

I am currently trying to use cx_Freeze to create a .exe file for my python scripts.
First, do cx_freeze get all data on the folder into the build folder?
Secondly, I'm having an issue when launching the .exe file. The fact that the first file opens the second one could be the issue ?
The console opened and closed, according to another post on Stackoverflow, I created a .bat file containing :

```
myfilename.exe%1
pause
```

to check out what the issue is and I got this issue :
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nelqm.png)

I've really no idea what to do next since I tried many things on the setup.py to make things working.
Here is the setup.py :

```
"""setup.py"""

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Roukira\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\Roukira\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6"

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}


setup(name="todolist",
      version="0.1",
      description = "A simple to do list with differnt tabs per account.",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable("login_system.py",base=None)])
```

I'm only using pillow as an external module but it doesn't seem to be the issue.
Thanks for your help by advance !

EDIT : I managed to fix it by adding the ddl missing files path inside the "include_files" option:

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "tkinter"], "include_files": ["to_do_list.py","336sur525.gif","384sur540.gif",
"accounts.txt","button_hide_2.gif","button_quit_2.gif","choose.gif","icone.ico","user.gif",
                r"C:\Users\Roukira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\Roukira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]}
```

My script was using a subprocess.call function to call another script, so it didn't work after becoming .exe, I added the .py file inside the "include_files" and it worked as intended.